# Column boolan to value GUI

Tags: sql-server

I cant seem to find a answer to this. I am using GUI to create a table and a column in there is called DuesPaid. I need this column boolan value to be false and it has the datatype of bit. How might one do this am I just missing where its at?

Comment: Your question is tagged `sql` only and you don't build UI with sql so we really have no idea what you are talking about. Please clarify your question

Comment: sorry, its in SQL SEVER. Its through the GUI to create tables, I need to set my column DuesPaid boolan to false but I am unsure how to through the GUI.

Comment: you need to set default value of bit column. if you run query then it will be like alter table tablename add DuesPaid bit default(0). 0 means false and 1 means true..in design there will be column property with name Default Value or Binding.

Comment: Useful doc link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BIT` is the type to store boolean values. 1 will mean true, and 0 will mean false. You can also compare it to strings 'true' and 'false'.

If you run this query:

```
SELECT IIF(CAST(1 AS BIT) = 'true', 'Yes', 'No') as [1 = true?]
     , IIF(CAST(0 AS BIT) = 'false', 'Yes', 'No') as [0 = false?]
     , IIF(CAST(0 AS BIT) = 'true', 'Yes', 'No') as [0 = true?]
```

You'll get the following:

```
1 = true? 0 = false? 0 = true?
--------- ---------- ---------
Yes       Yes        No
```